# Delete a specific image in folder?

Tags: php, mysql

How to delete image from a folder? My code deletes image path in database but does not delete in folder and I want also delete my images in folder.

My code is here

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
include_once('db.php');
$objDbCon = new db_connect();
$strSQL="DELETE FROM clients WHERE id='$id'";
$objQueryHome = $objDbCon->Query($strSQL);

if($objQueryHome){
    echo "Record has been deleted Succesfully";
}
else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

My image folder path is `../uploaded/`

Comment: What have you tried?  The code you show doesn't have anything to do with file operations.  When you Google "PHP delete file" does it not find anything?

Comment: You will need to use `unlink()` as already stated and also use a variable to the affected row holding the file's information/path etc. Therefore, you will need to fetch that record.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unlink()` php function

```
<?php

if($objQueryHome){
    unlink('image_path/image_name.jpg');
    echo "Record has been deleted Succesfully";
}
else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code --

```
<?php
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    include_once('db.php');

$objDbCon = new db_connect();
// first get the records --
$strSQLrecord ="Select * FROM clients WHERE id='$id'";
$result  = $objDbCon->Query($strSQLrecord);

while($newrow  = $result){
    # print_r($newrow) ; // just to get record details
    // get image name, may be something like below
    $imag = $newrow['image'] ; // where image is fields name in table where image-name is stored
    $fullpath = 'uploaded/'.$img ;
}

$strSQL="DELETE FROM clients WHERE id='$id'";
$objQueryHome = $objDbCon->Query($strSQL);

if($objQueryHome){
    unlink($fullpath) ; // unlink will be returning bool values if it was able to delete file otherwise check with the files path
    echo "Record has been deleted Succesfully";
}
else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```